# Обработка формы поиска JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Сделал по видеоуроку CRUD приложение. Надо добавить форму поиска, делаю поиск хотя бы по ID. Взял за основу контроллер, который отображает информацию об одном объекте:

```
@RequestMapping("userdata/{id}")
public String userData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));
    return "userdata";
}
```

Сделал контроллер:

```
@RequestMapping("/search/{id}")
public String search(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));
    return "search";
```

Создал search.jsp. И форму поиска:

```html
<form action="/search/${id}">
    <label for="id">ID:</label>
    <input path="id" type="number" id="id" name="id" placeholder="id"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

При поиске допустим 2 id открывает страницу search/?id=2. А нормально отображается на search/2. Что не так? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен `@RequestParam` вместо `@PathVariable`

```
@RequestMapping("/search/")
public String search(@RequestParam("id") int id, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));
    return "search";
```

И в форме

```
<form action="/search/">
    <label for="id">ID:</label>
    <input type="number" id="id" name="id" placeholder="id"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Работает! Пробовал и понял уже, что там что то с @RequestParam, но не убрал {id}.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте вместо `${id}` прописать `?id=${id}`

Comment: пробовал, не работает